# Optional typed immediately destructured parameters?

Tags: typescript

How do I write optional typed immediately destructured parameters?

To give an example I want the following function to be callable without providing any parameter.

```
const foo = ({bar}: {bar?: boolean}) => {};
```

As it is now, TypeScript complains that a parameter is missing.

Comment: @NinoFiliu: Np, go ahead

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Presumably you're unhappy about the following error:

```
const fooBad = ({ bar }?: { bar?: boolean }) => {}; // error!
// ┌──────────> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
// A binding pattern parameter cannot be optional in an implementation signature.
```

Which makes sense, because you can't destructure `undefined`.  What you *can* do, in TypeScript, is to use a [default function parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters).  This is treated like an optional parameter from the calling side of the function (so you can leave it out), and on the implementation side it sets a value of the parameter if it is `undefined`.

So, what do you want to destructure if someone calls `foo()`?  I'm guessing you want `bar` to be `undefined`, right?  So that would mean you either pass in something like `{bar: undefined}`, or (since `bar` is optional), the empty object `{}`:

```
const foo = ({ bar }: { bar?: boolean } = {}) => {
  console.log(bar);
};
```

I've added `console.log(bar)` so you can see what it becomes when you call it:

```
foo(); // undefined
foo({}); // undefined
foo({bar: true}); // true
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAhAhgExgXhgCgN4wBGKATjAL4D8AXDAcSTUYgDYCmKYFAlFgHx1yAbhgB6UTDYkSIEgEIAUOJiAYUkAApBs1aBAPz36Dho0ZhKJAQSIBLMGhsBzGAAcUUKFK4uSKALZt3ZMCcYCCwhGwwIE5QVuAoLDA2MJyJPk7sfmBQrrFcEFb2YK4AriRsAHQKCqCQsAggWLj0pBS0zYy0hKwcXOSNeOS8mAJ4CjAwNRAg7OUsIPY4DNxCCsJV9TjLYhLFtmxwNmxoChsDW8q7aPuHx6cMtFAkxWyDIsqPz1UKQA)

Comment: what if I want to give a default value to bar? `({ bar = true }: { bar: boolean } = {})` this is not okay. `({ bar = true }: { bar: boolean } = { bar: true })`  this one is okay but looks bad.

Comment: Followup questions on years-old answers don't generally get many eyes.  You might be looking for `({ bar = true }: { bar?: boolean } = {})` but any further discussion probably belongs in its own question post.  Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible, simply because it does not work in JavaScript either. For example, take this piece of JS:

```js
const foo = ({bar}) => {
  ...
};

foo({ bar: 123 }); // works
foo(); // error
```

Calling `foo` without an object parameter will result in this exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property `bar` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

This happens because the function implementation above is almost the same as writing:

```js
const foo = (arg1) => {
  let bar = arg1.bar;
};

foo();
```

The exception would be almost the same here, because `arg1.bar` attempts to access a property on an object that is `undefined`.

Long story short, JavaScript does not know "optional" parameters at runtime, therefore TypeScript doesn't allow them either.

Comment: Exactly. Note that it is still possible to write a `foo` implementation that can be called as `foo()` or as `foo({bar: <boolean>})` using typeguards - [playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAggJwOZQLxQN4CMCGyAXFLggDYT4B2AvgNwBQoksCmUAFAGYIqoB+EvCRoAlJgB8UGiCYBjONQDOwKLzjD2WHn3FScjKMagB6U+r2oto9AB8oAV2oATCNwCW1CC6MmP3Fwa-BLYfiYm5pa2NvzhEVCKKmp4hLQcwWhMCZEWAHQF8bSMDIwanKnEUMDIjhC0YkzljYxAA)

Comment: Note that this works:

`const foo = ({bar = null} = {}) => {
  console.log(bar)
};`